# Blank Context menu appearing when Setting Visibility of context menu to Hidden/Collapsed

Tags: wpf, contextmenu, datatrigger

I want to display either no context menu or a single item or two items in the context menu. I am using the MVVM pattern.

I have tried linking the context menu visibility to a bool property, this appears to work, but an empty context menu is rendered behind the current control, and becomes visible once the current control is closed. I've tried adding a data trigger bound to the same property - but this does not get fired. examining the visual tree shows that the default property is set for the context menu.

MenuItem Visibility works fine, so I can get 1 or 2 items displaying. But when No context menu is needed, a blank menu appears behind [image]

Note: same results with Visibility Hidden or Collapsed

The context menu is bound to a DataGrid as a static resource:

```xml
  RowStyle="{StaticResource PagedGridRowStyle}"
```

```xml
       <ContextMenu x:Key="BlankMenu" Visibility="Hidden">
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="PagedGridMenu"
                     Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}"
                     DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuActionName1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenuEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuActionCommand1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuActionName2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                      Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.ContextMenu2Enabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource VisConverter}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext}"
                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.MenuActionCommand2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style x:Key="PagedGridRowStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu"
                    Value="{StaticResource PagedGridMenu}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContextMenuEnabled}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource BlankMenu}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Note VisConverter simply toggles Visibility.Visible and Visibility.Collapsed on the boolean value

Style.Triggers - above:
This is an attempt to replace the complete context menu - to try to avoid the blank context menu opening behind control. - but it doesn't get fired.

```cs
       private bool _contextMenu2Enabled;
        public bool ContextMenu2Enabled
        {
            get => _contextMenu2Enabled;
            set
            {
                _contextMenu2Enabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private bool _contextMenuEnabled;
        public bool ContextMenuEnabled
        {
            get => _contextMenuEnabled;
            set
            {
                _contextMenuEnabled = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

Binding Error:

When ContextMenuEnabled = false: (and ContextMenu2Enabled = false)

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ContextMenuEnabled' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=33440573)'. BindingExpression:Path=ContextMenuEnabled; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=33440573); target element is 'DataGridRow' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

The Context menu does not appear, but an empty context menu is rendered behind the datagrid, and becomes visible after the datagrid is closed

When ContextMenuEnabled = true (and ContextMenu2Enabled = false)
Same BindingExpression Error - but the context menu shows a single item as expected.

When ContextMenuEnabled = true and ContextMenu2Enabled = true
Same BindingExpression error, - but Both Context menu items are shown as expected.

Comment: Where is the `ContextMenuEnabled` property defined? And why don't you just set the `ContextProperty` to `null` instead of setting it to an empty menu with no items: `<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>`?

Comment: `ContextMenuEnabled` is on the ViewModel .  Thanks for informing me about `{x:Null}` I now know how to nullify in xaml :)  And I changed the data trigger binding to `Binding="{Binding DataContext.ContextMenuEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" ` which has solved the problem and fixed the BindingExpression Errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of displaying an empty `ContextMenu`, you could set the `ContextMenu` property to `null` in your setter:

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{x:Null}"/>
```

And if the `ContextMenuEnabled` property is defined in your view model, you should use a `RelativeSource` to bind to it:

```
Binding="{Binding DataContext.ContextMenuEnabled, 
   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
```